# Solution of the Wave Equation by Separation of Variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations, physics, mathematical-physics, wave-equation

We know for

$\left\{\begin{array}{cccc}\dfrac{1}{c^2}u_{tt}&=&u_{xx}\hspace{0.25cm}x\in [0,L]&\\
u(0,t)&=&u(L,t)=0\\
u(x,0)&=&f(x)\\
u_t(x,0)&=&g(x)
\end{array}\right.$

$$u(x,t)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sin\left(\frac{k\pi x}{L}\right)\left[a_k\cos\left(\frac{ck\pi t}{L}\right)+b_k\sin\left(\frac{ck\pi t}{L}\right)\right]$$
and
$$a_k=\frac{2}{L}\int_0^Lf(x)\sin\left(\frac{k\pi x}{L}\right)dx\hspace{1cm}b_k=\frac{2}
{ck\pi}\int_0^Lg(x)\sin\left(\frac{k\pi x}{L}\right)dx$$

\

My question is for the case when $x\in[-L,L]$, what is $u(x,t)$? And how could I find $a_k$ and $b_k$

What I did

$\left\{\begin{array}{cccc}\dfrac{1}{c^2}u_{tt}&=&u_{xx}\hspace{0.25cm}x\in [-L,L]&\\
u(-L,t)&=&u(L,t)=0\\
u(x,0)&=&f(x)\\
u_t(x,0)&=&g(x)
\end{array}\right.$

$u(x,t)=\Psi(x)\theta(t)\\
u_{tt}=\Psi(x)\ddot{\theta}(t)\\
u_{xx}=\theta(t)\ddot{\Psi}(x)$

__

$\Psi(x)=e^{rx}\\
\Psi'(x)=re^{rx}\\
\Psi''(x)=r^2e^{rx}$

__

$r^2e^{rx}=-\lambda \Psi(x)\Rightarrow r=\sqrt{\lambda}i\Rightarrow \Psi(x)=e^{\sqrt{\lambda}i}\Rightarrow \Psi(x)=c_1\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}x)+c_2\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x)\\
\Psi(L)=c_1\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}L)+c_2\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}L)\\
\Psi(-L)=c_1\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}(-L))+c_2\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}(-L))$
\
Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you sure your question is correct? Your boundary conditions are at $x = \pm \pi$ but you are trying to solve the PDE on $[0,L]$?

Comment: Two comments: first one, I think your boundary conditions should be at $x = 0$ and $x=L$ not $x = \pm \pi$. Second, how did you get this solution? It seems that you got it using separation of variables. To solve the problem for $x \in [-L,L]$, the procedure is the same but now you have to adapt the boundary conditions.

Comment: @IamWill that's what I did but now don't know how to continue